# Connecting to web service via Proxy server which has NTLM

Tags: java, ntlm, proxy-server, ntlm-authentication

I want to know the parameter to use to connect to Webservice via internal proxy service which has NTLM Authentication.
Initially I Was able to connect to external web service via internal proxy using java parameters like

```
-Dhttp.proxyPort= -DHttp.proxyUser= -Dhttp.proxyHost= -Dhttp.proxyPassword= -Djava.net.useSystemProxies=true
```

But now they enabled the NTLM Auth on internal Proxy server , so my request to external Web service via proxy is failing.
I tried adding extra parameter like `-Dhttp.auth.ntlm.domain=` but its not working.

Is there any other parameter I need to pass so that I Can connect to external webservice via NTLM proxy server ? or Any additional code I have to write in java ?